# Setting up docker on Mac OS - php-intl cannot be installed

Tags: php, macos, docker, boot2docker

I have the following problem:

I want set up a development environment on my Mac using docker and boot2docker.

For that I created an image using the below Dockerfile.

The Problem is, **that my php-intl-Extension cannot be installed**.. I tried various method. For example to enable it in php.ini via:

```
extension=php_intl.so
```

None of the methods will work. Here is the content of my Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:5.5-apache

# use own php.ini file
COPY config/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/

# get some php-extensions
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libmcrypt-dev \
        libpng12-dev \
        libicu52 \
        libicu-dev \
        zlib1g-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) iconv mcrypt \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libmemcached-dev \
    && pecl install memcached \
    && docker-php-ext-enable memcached

# Install intl (not working yet):
RUN pecl install intl

# use own src file
COPY src/ /var/www/html/
```

Can anyone help? That would be so great, because this problem takes a lot of time by now. Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use PECL, why don't you just use:

```
docker-php-ext-install intl
```

Generally you also need to `apt-get install libicu-dev` for dependencies, but you already have that.